# Error "Compiled with problems: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')" occurs from using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The error occurs for me in a Create React App with only the following changes. My App.js looks like:

```
// App.js

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HelloWorld from './Components/HelloWorld';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HelloWorld} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And Components/HelloWorld.js looks like:

```
// Components/HelloWorld.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Instead of displaying Hello World!, the error message comes up.

Here is the full text of the error I'm getting:

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at Object.useRef (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:47954:25)
    at BrowserRouter (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:44414:55)
    at renderWithHooks (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:21295:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:24581:17)
    at beginWork (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:25877:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:10887:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:10931:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:10988:35)
    at beginWork$1 (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:30862:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:30109:16)

ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at Object.useRef (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:47954:25)
    at BrowserRouter (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:44414:55)
    at renderWithHooks (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:21295:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:24581:17)
    at beginWork (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:25877:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:10887:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:10931:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:10988:35)
    at beginWork$1 (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:30862:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:30109:16)

ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at Object.useRef (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:47954:25)
    at BrowserRouter (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:44414:55)
    at renderWithHooks (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:21295:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:24581:17)
    at beginWork (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:25877:20)
    at beginWork$1 (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:30840:18)
    at performUnitOfWork (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:30109:16)
    at workLoopSync (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:30032:9)
    at renderRootSync (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:30005:11)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (LOCALHOST_HERE/static/js/bundle.js:29497:24)
```

(Note: The `LOCALHOST_HERE`s are actually just `localhost:3000`; I replaced them in the text here because stackoverflow was giving me "Your question appears to be spam", likely because it saw a lot of http web addresses.)

I believe the issue has something to do with the React Router, because if I replace `function App()` to not use the router, as below, then I don't get the error and the Hello World! message successfully displays in the browser.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HelloWorld />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It seems like whatever's going wrong is happening within the React Router, but I don't know how to deal with it. The problem originally appeared in a larger app; this Create React App minimal example is the result of my attempting to isolate it.

I tried googling "Compiled with problems: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')", which gave some results indicating that the issue might have something to do with conflicting versions of different packages. But the suggested solutions either had no effect or were already true for my code (e.g. including `"react": "^18.2.0"` in `package.json`). I've gone over documentation for, and examples, of the React Router, but without getting any results. I'm guessing something is wrong with my environment, but I don't know what, or how to fix it?

What can I do to fix this? Thank you, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The `BrowserRouter` maintains its own internal reference to a history object using `React.useRef`. The error is that `React` is null for some reason. Have you ensured the project has all dependencies properly installed? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] that includes your package.json file? If you fix the route to use the correct RRDv6 route APIs, e.g. `<Route path="/" element={< HelloWorld />} />`, does the issue persist?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not import css to your index.js

Try to import index needed for your bootstrap in index.js.
Ex.:
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).